# Generating all size k subsets of {0, 1, 2, ... n-1}

Tags: c++, stl

I want to generate all cardinality `k` subsets of `{0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}` in C++. In Haskell, I would do:

```
sets 0 n = [[]]
sets k n = [i:s | i <- [0..n-1], s <- sets (k-1) i]
```

Or in Python:

```
def sets(k, n):
    if k == 0:
        return [()]
    return ((i,)+s for i in range(n) for s in sets(k-1, i))
```

So, for example, (line breaks added for clarity)

```
ghci> sets 2 8
[[1,0],
 [2,0],[2,1],
 [3,0],[3,1],[3,2],
 [4,0],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],
 [5,0],[5,1],[5,2],[5,3],[5,4],
 [6,0],[6,1],[6,2],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5],
 [7,0],[7,1],[7,2],[7,3],[7,4],[7,5],[7,6]]
```

What would be the "C++ way" of doing this? Note that I'm not asking *how* to solve the problem. I'm asking about what data types would be considered "normal" by C++ programmers.

<sup>(For reference, I'm vaguely familiar with C++ and somewhat familiar with C.)</sup>

Comment: Forget somewhat familiar with C. It won't help you at all.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but I noticed no one suggested iterative algorithm to do this. See [my note](http://blazsovdat.com/subsets.pdf) on generating all k-subsets of a n-set for description of such an algorithm and [its implementation](https://gist.github.com/blazs/9638794). (It turned out to be essentially the same as one of the algorithms Knuth describes in his Volume 4.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a naive, recursive approach, which implements the classical combinatorial identity:

```
binom(n + 1, k + 1) = binom(n, k + 1) + binom(n, k)
```

```
#include <set>

typedef std::set<int> intset;

std::set<intset> subsets(std::size_t k, intset s)
{
    if (k == 0 || s.empty() || s.size() < k) { return { { } }; }

    if (s.size() == k) { return { s }; }

    auto x = *s.begin();
    s.erase(s.begin());

    std::set<intset> result;

    for (auto & t : subsets(k - 1, s))
    {
        auto r = std::move(t);
        r.insert(x);
        result.insert(std::move(r));
    }

    for (auto & t : subsets(k, s))
    {
        results.insert(std::move(t));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
auto ss = subsets(3, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4});
```

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <prettyprint.hpp>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) return 1;

    auto k = std::stoul(argv[1]);
    auto n = std::stoul(argv[2]);

    intset s;
    for (auto i = 0U; i != n; ++i) s.insert(i);

    std::cout << subsets(k, s) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rosetta Code has [an implementation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C.2B.2B) that works by taking the first `k` entries of permutations of the list `0, 1, ..., n-1`. It uses the C++ STL.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a set of all subsets is called the [*power set*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), and Wikipedia has quite a bit written on it. One section is even dedicated to [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms) for doing what you want. This particular problem requests the [subsets of limited cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Subsets_of_limited_cardinality) of the power set. You should probably use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Answer (score 1):

A quick implementation (using recursion) of this in C would be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 8
#define K 3

void print_combination(int* combination, int k)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++){
        printf("%d ", combination[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void find_all_combinations(int idx, int* in_use, int* combination,
        int n, int k)
{
    int i;
    if (idx == k){
        print_combination(combination, k);
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (in_use[i]){
            continue;
        }

        in_use[i] = 1;
        combination[idx++] = i + 1;

        find_all_combinations(idx, in_use, combination, n, k);

        combination[--idx] = 0;
        in_use[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Ensure that the arrays are initialized with zeroes. */
    int in_use[N] = {0};
    int curr_combination[K] = {0};
    find_all_combinations(0, in_use, curr_combination, N, K);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more recursive solution in C++. The function `ksubsets` does not expects the input (`arr`) to be a set, it can by any container that can be iterated (in the example I use vector), and it can contain duplicates.
The function generates all `k-sized` subsets of the numbers stored in `arr`. The subsets are stored in the `res`.

```
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void ksubsets(const vector<int>& arr, unsigned ksize, unsigned idx,
    vector<int>& tmp, vector<vector<int>>& res)
{
    if (ksize < 1) {
        res.push_back(tmp);
        return;
    }
    for (unsigned i = idx; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        tmp.push_back(arr[i]);
        ksubsets(arr, ksize - 1, i + 1, tmp, res);
        tmp.pop_back();
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>arr = {1,2,3,4};
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    vector<int> cur;
    unsigned ksize = 3;
    ksubsets(arr, ksize, 0, cur, result); 

   // use here the result, it contains vectors {1,2,3}, {1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4}
}
```