# Initialise list correctly

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, initialization

I am reading a file line by line. Each line is read in such that it gets split into a list (of length 13) that contains sublists (of an arbitrary length (usually between one and four). This is mandated by the data structure of the file that I am reading.

I carry out a check on each line to see if it contains desired data and then want to save it if it does.

It is saved into a list (called `results`) containing 13 fields, each again containing several lists to obtain a structure like the following: `results[0] = [line1[0], line2[0], ...]; results[1] = [line1[1], line2[1], ...]; ...; results[12] = [line1[12], line2[12], ...]` (`results[i][j]` is a list of length 1 containing a string).

I would solve this by:

```
results = []
for i in line:
    results[i].append(line[i])
```

To do this though the list `results` needs to be properly initialised first which I can't do manually as I don't know if my first line contains an entry that I want to save a priori and I don't want to initialise it with random values which I have to delete later as deleting the first entry in a list is quite inefficient as far as I know. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you need to hold exactly 13 sub-lists, just create it with 13 empty lists:

```
results = [[] for _ in range(13)]
```

Note: You cannot do:

```
results = [[]] * 13
```

because that will mirror a reference to a *single* list 13 times; mutating any entry will mutate all of them. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19375525/364696).